# SQL Server 2008 R2: Avoid vice versa records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table with two columns:

**Table**: vv

```
CREATE TABLE vv
(
    cola INT,
    colb INT
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO vv VALUES (1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(4,3);
```

**Records I have**:

```
SELECT * FROM vv;

Cola    Colb
------------
1   2
2   1
3   4
4   3
```

**Note**: Now I want to remove vice versa records from the table. Like in my table I have 
record `1,2` and `2,1`, I just want to keep the only one value whichever appear first in the 
table.

**Expected Result should be**:

If I order by `1` in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM vv
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Cola = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

The result should be:

```
Cola    Colb
-------------   
1       2
3       4
```

If I order by `4` in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM vv
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Cola = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

The result should be:

```
Cola    Colb
-------------
4       3
1       2
```

If I order by `3` in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM vv
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Cola = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

The result should be:

```
Cola    Colb
-------------   
3       4 
1       2
```

Comment: what are the quires in your expected outpput section?

Comment: @Dark Knight, I just want to write select statement for that.

Comment: What do you mean by which appear first? How do you know which is first?

Comment: If you want removal of duplicates in pairs this will do http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8fa3/2

Comment: @FelixPamittan, I will come to know it by passing the value to order by, as you can in the expected output section.

Comment: Perhaps too late, but I've already answered this on DBA Admins forums: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89171/remove-duplicates-from-different-columns/89199#89199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try rearranging them in new columns then do a `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` the new columns:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        firstCol = CASE WHEN cola >= colb  THEN colb ELSE cola END,
        secondCol = CASE WHEN cola < colb  THEN colb ELSE cola END
    FROM vv
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY firstCol, secondCol
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN Cola = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
             )
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT cola, colb
FROM CteFinal
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Cola = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

*You have to replace the `ORDER BY` clause to achieve the desired order.*

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch The `CTE` adds two new columns with `firstCol` having the lesser value and the `secondCol` having the greater value, basically just ordering the two columns. Then `CteFinal` assigns a `ROW_NUMBER` for each `firstCol`-`secondCol` combination. That way, no two _vice versa_ row will have the same value for `ROW_NUMBER`. Then you have to modify the `ORDER BY` clause to determine which row is _first_. Then `SELECT` and filter for `rn=1` to get the _first_ row of each _vice versa_ records.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
;WITH cte1 AS(SELECT * FROM @vv WHERE cola = 3),
      cte2 AS(SELECT v.* FROM @vv v
              CROSS JOIN cte1 c 
              WHERE NOT ((v.cola = c.colb AND v.colb = c.cola) OR (v.cola = c.cola AND v.colb = c.colb)))
SELECT * FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT c1.* FROM cte2 c1
join cte2 c2 ON c1.cola = c2.colb AND c1.colb = c2.cola AND c1.cola < c2.cola
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd take the following approach:

1) Create the table with a slight twist:

```
CREATE TABLE vv
(
    cola INT,
    colb INT
);

alter table vv add constraint [CK_a_less_than_b] check (cola < colb);
alter table vv add constraint [UQ_a_b] unique (cola, colb);
```

2) Inserts happen through the ff procedure:

create procedure dbo.insertVV (@a int, @b int)
as begin

```
   if (@a > @b)
      insert into dbo.vv
         (cola, colb)
      values
         (@b, @a);
   else
      insert into dbo.vv
         (cola, colb)
      values
         (@a, @b);
end
```

Alternatively, if you don't/can't trust that people with use the sproc to do their inserts, you could put the above in an instead of insert trigger.

You could also get fancy with step 1 and create a computed column that is defined as a value that provides a guaranteed order and then put the unique index on *that* and then step 2 is unnecessary.